# Copying visual studio projects between solutions

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, copying

Whats the easiest way to copy a visual studio project between distinct solutions? can i just copy the folder containing the project data in windows explorer?

Comment: Why do you want to copy projects around? Worst kind of copy/paste I can think of.

Comment: Do you really want to copy the project? The same project can be part of many solutions, just "add existing project". Changes will then be available to all solutions. Otherwise copying the folder works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can copy the project folder and just add it to the new solution. Also note, that you can have a single project in multiple solutions, if for instance you have a solution for each project and a global solutions for all the projects you have.